# Render React's components into the different DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to render components into different elements.

I have the sidebar and the main part. I should use React for the sidebar and the main part.

I can render:

```
React.render(
  <Sidebar />,
  document.getElementById('sidebar')
);
React.render(
  <Main />,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

But one component should work with another. I can't render it into `body` because my site works on JavaScript. And I want to add one part on React.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried that? It should be fine.

Comment: @Shawn, I need to send props from sidebar to main block. This is my problem.

Comment: Can you not use the flux pattern and have the props from the sidebar pushed to a flux action and the main block use the flux store to listen for the parameters?

Comment: @Theston.EFox, is it possible with Flux only?

Comment: @AndryName No, you can do it with other Event mechanisms as well but Flux caters well for React based applications.

Comment: As @limelights says, you don't have to use Flux, but ReactJS does Flux really well, you should at least try and use Flux as your mechanism as it really makes everything nice and neat. I'm working on an example repository on github at the mo. if you want a link to it then let me know and I'll post it here, maybe it can help you

Comment: @Theston.EFox Shameless plug, I've already made a pretty good example of that here https://github.com/limelights/todo-reflux